# Change WSL2 memory

Tags: docker, memory, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I`ve been trying to change the memory of Docker from my Win 11 PC using wsl2. I followed the windows tutorial of creating a ".wslconfig" file, but I have no success. Everytime I run the code, I still get the default memory of 7GB (I want to increase it up to 14GB. When I create the .wslconfig file, the properties tell me that it is saved as a .txt file even tough the .txt is not showing. What am I missing here?
[image: wsl]
[image: properties]
[image: docker]
[image: general]
[image: adjust]

Answer (score 0):

the file you created is a .txt file even though windows hides the extension sometimes. make sure when your saving the file using notepad you specify the type as "all files".
[image]